# Multidimensional Gaussian integrals with a complex quadratic term

Tags: integration, gaussian-integral

In the link https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_integrals_in_quantum_field_theory, it is written without proof that 
$$
\int \exp\left(-\frac{i}{2} x \cdot A \cdot x +iJ \cdot x \right) d^nx =\sqrt{\frac{(2\pi i)^n}{\det A}} \exp \left( -{i\over 2} J \cdot A^{-1} \cdot J \right),
$$
where $A$ is a real symmetric matrix and the integration domain is over $\mathbb{R}^n$.
This integral looks quite trivial, but it has a puzzling aspect that I am going to describe now.

First of all, let's consider the two dimensional case where $A_{11} = a$, $A_{12} = A_{21} = b$ and $A_{22} = c$ with $J=0$. 
In this case, the above integral can be simplified as
$$
I= \int \exp\left( 
    -\frac{i}{2} \left[ 
    a x^2 + 2 b x y + c y^2
\right]
\right)dx dy. 
$$

Now, I want to integrate this equation one by one with regard to $x$ and then $y$. If we perform the integrals, one arrives at
$$ 
I = \sqrt{\frac{2\pi i}{a}} \int dy e^{\frac{i y^2 \left(a c-b^2\right)}{a}} = \sqrt{\frac{2\pi i}{a}} \sqrt{\frac{a \times 2\pi i}{\det A}} = \sqrt{ \frac{4\pi^2}{|\det A|}} \times e^{(\textrm{sgn}(a) + \textrm{sgn}(\det A /a)) \frac{\pi i}{4}},
$$
where the square root takes the principle value from the Fresnel integral calculation shown in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fresnel_integral. 
What puzzles me now is the sign dependence of $a$, thus the existence of $\textrm{sgn}(a)$. Even worse, if we choose the different integration order, thus with respect to $y$ first and then $x$, we have different result, which is given by
$$ 
I = \sqrt{ \frac{4\pi^2}{|\det A|}} \times e^{(\textrm{sgn}(c) + \textrm{sgn}(\det A /c))\frac{\pi i}{4}}.
$$
This is clearly not acceptable. There must be some gap above or the integral is defined in an unusual sense. Can you explain what is going on? Is $I$ well-defined? Also, or directly, can you point out the direct proof of the first equality?

Comment: For starters, $\textrm{sgn}(c) + \textrm{sgn}(\det A /c) = \textrm{sgn}(a) + \textrm{sgn}(\det A /a)$ always, so you at least have consistency (this is tedious but not hard to show. Work with cases, and note that in some cases the signs of $a$ and $c$ are coupled through that of $\det(A)$ since $b^2\ge0$).

Comment: Further, the case with apparent ambiguity in your final formula ($c<0, \det A >0$) seems to work out fine as well, and the error seems to be in the expression for the principle value. For reference, see [this](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SquareRoot.html), with particular attention to the last formula before the references, and the cases therein.