# Multivariate gaussian integral with quadratic term outside exponent

Tags: definite-integrals, normal-distribution, gaussian-integral

I have searched around, but I have not found a solution to Gaussian integrals of the following form:
$$\int (x^\intercal R x)\exp\left[-\frac{1}{2} \left(x^\intercal Ax\right) + Bx\right]d^n x$$
Here, $B$ is an $n$-dimensional vector, $R$ and $A$ are $n\times n$ matrices, and we integrate over the space of $n$-dimensional vectors $x$ with real values.  Explicitly, $x^\intercal R x = \sum_{i,j=1}^n x_i R_{ij} x_j$ and $B x = \sum_{i=1}^n B_i x_i$.

Presumably, $A$ must be a positive-definite matrix to assure convergence.  Other than that, I think the elements of $R$, $A$, and $B$ can be arbitrary complex numbers.  However, I would be interested in evaluating this integral for restrictions, e.g., if $A$ is also real-valued (and therefore symmetric).

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_integral) evaluates the special cases of $R=0$ and $n=1$.

(Note that the above integral is *not* addressed by similarly-worded [question 187923](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1879239/multidimensional-gaussian-integrals-with-a-complex-quadratic-term), which uses "quadratic term" to refer to the term with $A$ in the exponent rather than $R$ outside the exponent.)

Answer (score 1):

Whoops, I missed the standard trick that is in fact listed on Wikipedia [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_integral#n-dimensional_and_functional_generalization).  For matrices with real elements,

$$\begin{align}
\int &(x^\intercal R x)\exp\left[-\frac{1}{2} \left(x^\intercal Ax\right) + Bx\right]d^n x \\ &= \sum_{ij} R_{ji} \partial_{B_i}\partial_{B_j}\int \exp\left[-\frac{1}{2} \left(x^\intercal Ax\right) + Bx\right]d^n x\\
&=\sum_{ij} R_{ji} \partial_{B_i}\partial_{B_j}\sqrt{\frac{(2\pi)^n}{|A|}}\exp\left[\frac{1}{2} \left(B A^{-1} B^\intercal\right)\right]\\
&=\sqrt{\frac{(2\pi)^n}{|A|}}\sum_{ij} R_{ji} \left[(A^{-1})_{ij} + (A^{-1}B^\intercal)_{i}(BA^{-1})_{j}\right]\exp\left[\frac{1}{2} \left(B A^{-1} B^\intercal\right)\right]\\
&=\sqrt{\frac{(2\pi)^n}{|A|}}\left[\mathrm{Tr}\left(R A^{-1}\right) + BA^{-1}RA^{-1}B^\intercal\right]\exp\left[\frac{1}{2} \left(B A^{-1} B^\intercal\right)\right]
\end{align}$$

Comment: Hi Jess, I am trying to find out an integral exactly like this one but with the term before the exponential raised to some power of n with n being constant. Do you have any suggestions on how I could go about doing that?

Comment: Hi @alex, if the power $n$ is an explicit small integer, like 2, you could explicitly compute $\int (x^\intercal R x)^2 \exp[\cdots] dx = (\sum_{ij} R_{ji} \partial_{B_i} \partial_{B_j} )^2 \int  \exp[\cdots] dx = \sum_{ijk\ell} R_{ji} R_{\ell k}  \partial_{B_i} \partial_{B_j}  \partial_{B_k} \partial_{B_\ell}  \int  \exp[\cdots] dx$ and finish similarly as the above. It's laborious but definitely do-able.  Unforunately, I don't know of an abstract expression in terms of arbitrary $n$, although I suspect one could be derived. Good luck!

Comment: Hi Jess, my comment is to solve this question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4464274/evaluation-of-power-times-gaussian-multivariable-integral?noredirect=1#comment9354526_4464274) the integral will need to be solved for a high value of n, but the matrices are 2x1 and 2x2, there is a solution that I found but it seems to be reported wrong, and it uses a 1d integral with a solution with a thermite poynomial

Comment: Right now I'm thinking there are three ways of doing this, doing some change to polar coordinates, since the 1d integral has a cos term and it's from 0 to infinity, changing variables with a rotation matrix to diagonalize R and deal with the rest of the terms applying another 1d integral, or maybe the only way to do it is using the matrices that go in R A and B in the original problem and use some pattern there to solve it. I am not to familiar with the terms you're using, what is $\partial_B$? I'm guessing that's some notation used by physicists is it a partial derivative?

Comment: Yes sorry, $\partial_{B_i} :=  \partial/\partial B_i$ is just short hand for the operator that performs a partial derivative with respect to particular element $B_i$ of $B$.